# Matlab: error using bsxfun Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other

Tags: matlab, normalization, bsxfun, matconvnet

I'm trying to run https://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/quick/,

I wrote the following codes (network is Alexnet):

```
im = imread('/home/levi/Codes/MM_space//n01443537_22563.JPEG');
im_ = single(im);
im_ = imresize(im_, net.meta.normalization.imageSize(1:2));
```

Until this part is fine, `_im` becomes a

```
227*227*3 single
```

However, after running this:

```
im_ = bsxfun(@minus, im_, net.meta.normalization.averageImage);
```

I receive the error:

> Error using bsxfun Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays
> must match each other

According to the webpage it should work, but is not working... I also did a little search but still struggling with solving it.

`net.meta.normalization.averageImage` is

```
3×1 single column vector

  122.7395
  114.8967
  101.5919
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply an operation between a `227*227*3` matrix and a `3*1` (or `3*1*1`) array. `bsxfun` tries to expand the singleton dimensions (i.e. dimensions of size `1` in the array) to match the size of the other array, but to do that the other dimensions must already match. They don't because your non-singleton dimension in the array is dimension 1, where the matching dimension of size 3 in the matrix is dimension 3.

You can reshape the array so that the matching sizes are aligned

```
% Make the average array a 1*1*3
avg = reshape( net.meta.normalization.averageImage, 1, 1, [] );
% Now do subtraction
im_ = bsxfun(@minus, im_, avg);
```

Note that since MATLAB 2016b, you can use [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) without requiring `bsxfun`. The same condition applies with the input dimensions, so you still need the `reshape` above, but then you can just do

```
im_ = im_ - avg;
```

Comment: I could solve the problem. Thank you very much :)